# Getting lost in Scala Futures

Tags: scala, akka

I'm slowly wrapping my brain around Futures in Scala, and have a bit of a layer cake going on that I'm trying to unravel.

The specific use case is a `DeferredResolver` in [sangria-graphql](http://sangria-graphql.org/) + akka. I've stolen their demo code, which looks like this

```
  Future.fromTry(Try(
    friendIds map (id => CharacterRepo.humans.find(_.id == id) orElse CharacterRepo.droids.find(_.id == id))))
```

and added my own modification to it. Theirs does an in-memory lookup, whereas mine asks something of another actor:

```
  Future.fromTry(Try(
    accountIds match {
      case h :: _ =>
        val f = sender ? TargetedMessage(h)
        val resp = Await.result(f, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[TargetedMessage]
        marshallAccount(resp.body)

      case _ => throw new Exception("Not found")
    }
  ))
```

The pertinent piece here is that I pick the first element in the list, send it to an `ActorRef` that I got elsewhere and wait for the result. This works. What I'd like to do, however, is not have to wait for the result here, but return the whole thing as a `Future`

```
  Future.fromTry(Try(
    accountIds match {
      case h :: _ =>
        sender ? TargetedMessage(h) map {
          case resp:TargetedMessage => marshallAccount(resp.body)
        }

      case _ => throw new Exception("Not found")
    }
  ))
```

This doesn't work. When this is consumed, instead of being of type `Account` (the return type of function `marshallAccount`, it's of type Promise. If I understand correctly, it's because instead of having a return type of `Future[Account]`, this has a type of `Future[Future[Account]]`

How do I flatten this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong API method. `Future.fromTry` is used to create an immediately resolved Future, meaning the call is not actually asynchronous. Dive into the implementation of `Future.fromTry` which will take you to:

```
def fromTry[T](result: Try[T]): Promise[T] = new impl.Promise.KeptPromise[T](result)
```

A promise kept is basically something that **has already happened**, so just like `Future.successful` this is just used to ensure the right return type or similar, it's not actually a way to make something async.

The reason why the return type is `Future[Future[Something]]` is because you are trying to wrap something that already returns a future into another future.

The ask pattern, namely `sender ? TargetMessage(h)` is a way to **ask** something of an actor and await for a result, which will return a future.

The correct way to approach this:

```
val future: Future[Account] = accountIds match {
  case h :: _ => sender ? TargetedMessage(h) map (marshallAccount(_.body)
  case _ => Future.failed(throw new Exception("Not found"))
}
```

Basically you need to use `Future.failed` to return a failed future from an exception if you want to keep the return type consistent. It's worth reviewing [**this tutorial**](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) to learn a bit more about Futures and how to write application logic with them.